# System i (iSeries, AS/400) Message Queuing Options

Tags: message-queue, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to find options for MQ on the iSeries besides WebSphere MQ.  Does anyone have experience with this?  Is it possible?  Could I run a pure java MQ server like OpenMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why not, though I haven't personally tried.  However, I would strongly recommend going with a software package that supports [AMQP](http://amqp.org/).  I believe it's planned for OpenMQ, but isn't actually implemented yet.  [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) is probably something you should look at.  It's almost as good as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), but written in Java and JMS compliant.

Comment: Excellent advice, I'll start looking into Apache Qpid.